# Maps of degree $k$ and their behavior on higher homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $f \colon S^n \to S^n$ is a map of degree $k$ and suppose we know what group $\pi_j (S^n)$  for $j > n$ is. Is it possible to know what kind of map is induced on $\pi_j(S^n)$ by $f$? For example if $\pi_j(S^n)=\mathbb Z_2$, is $f_*$ mapping the generator to $k$-times the generator?

Comment: not sure whether it helps, but in the case of $n=2$ and $j=3$ ($\pi_3(S^2)=\mathbb Z$) the map $f_*$ multiplies the generator by $k^2$

Comment: Could you provide a proof?

Comment: A more direct proof must be possible, but here is one with differential forms. If $g:S^3\to S^2$ is smooth, $B\in\Omega^2(S^2)$ is the area form, and $A\in\Omega^3(S^3)$ is such that $dA=g^*B$ then the class of $g$ in $\pi_3(S^2)$ is (up to a multiple) the Hopf invariant $\int_{S^3}A\wedge dA$. To compute it for $g\circ f$ we have to replace $B$ with $f^*B$, which has the same class as $kB$, so in the end we have to multiply $A$ by $k$.